# Created variable inside for loop can't be accessed when using a class

Tags: python

The following code runs fine if I don't use an object oriented style

```
settings = "test"
for i in range(3):
    globals()[f"var{i + 1}"] = 10 + i
    
print(settings)
print(var1)
```

it outputs the following:

```
test
10
```

However when I use the same code inside a class it does not work anymore:

```
class Gui():
    def __init__(self):
        self.settings = "test"
        for i in range(3):
            globals()[f"self.var{i + 1}"] = 10 + i


    def run(self):
        print(self.settings)
        print(self.var1)

gui = Gui()
gui.run()
```

I get the following error:

```
test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/loose/PycharmProjects/AutomatedCNNImageClassifier/python/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    gui.run()
  File "C:/Users/loose/PycharmProjects/AutomatedCNNImageClassifier/python/test.py", line 10, in run
    print(self.var1)
AttributeError: 'Gui' object has no attribute 'var1'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why does it not work? Since I want to access the variable *var* from another function I have to use *self.var* just like I did with *self.settings*.

Comment: All you are doing is defining `globals()['self.var1']`, etc directly on the `globals` dictionary. This code smells really bad, why are you doing this rather than just using a list?

Comment: Note that there isn't anything special about the `self.` in `f"self.var{i + 1}"`. You could have just as easily written `f"I like pancakes var{i + 1}"`. You're in no way using the local variable `self`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how globals work and how the self variable works.

When you do `globals()['myvariable'] = 10` then you are creating a variable inside the global scope named `myvariable` and assigning it a value of 10. You can now retrieve that variable anywhere with `myvariable` like `print(myvariable)`.

However python doesn't support variables with `.` in them. So if you do `globals()['myvariable.one']` and then try to use `myvariable.one`, Python is now looking for a variable named `myvariable` and then retrieving an attribute of that object named `one`. So it doesn't work.

If you want to add a variable to the class and retrieve it via `self.myvariable` then you would want to do this.

```
class Gui():
    def __init__(self):
        self.settings = "test"
        for i in range(3):
            setattr(self, f"var{i + 1}", 10 + i)


    def run(self):
        print(self.settings)
        print(self.var1)

gui = Gui()
gui.run()
```

Now it will run.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is simple:

`self` refers to the instance, but in your case, you're defining a variable `self.var1` globally.
So it is not bound to your class context.

Hence why the error message appears.
You really have no var1 inside of your class.

You can try it for yourself, assign `self.var1` inside the class a specific value and then run it.
You will be able to retrieve the assigned value.